# Move all files in a directory to a new directory

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

I have a C# Windows Forms Application where I want to move all files on the Desktop to another directory. For testing purposes, I have just made a folder on the Desktop called "Test" where I want the files to be moved. I have this code run right when the first form opens:

```
try
        {
            string dest = @"C:\Users\Billeh\Desktop\Test\";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Billeh\Desktop\");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                File.Move(file, dest);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

However, this doesn't seem to do anything. It just goes on and opens the form like it was skipped. No message box pops up, and I know that it isn't being skipped because if I make it bring up a random message box in the try statement, it comes up fine. I don't know what's wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: _dest_ cannot be simply the name of the destination **folder**. It need to have also the name of the file. Path.GetFilename is required here

Comment: What if there are no files currently in the destination folder? By "It needs to also have the name of the file" do you mean one inside the destination folder?

Comment: No, simply it is not enough to give the destination folder. File.Move requires a name for the target of the move. Indeed this method is also used to _rename_ a file in the same folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) requires a *destination file* not just a destination folder.
You need to decide how to name the moved file in the destination folder. It could be the same name of the source file or another name of your choice. Path.GetFilename could be of help if you want to maintain the old name.

Notice also that [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) is better than GetFiles because allows you to start the moving action without loading all the files names in memory first.

```
try
{
    string dest = @"C:\Users\Billeh\Desktop\Test";
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Billeh\Desktop\"))
    {
        string destFile = Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(file))
        if(!File.Exists(destFile))
            File.Move(file, destFile);

    }
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Consider also that File.Move cannot overwrite an existing file in the target folder. If the file exists an IOException is raised. So, if you want to overwrite you need to Delete the destination file before but, in any case, you need to add a check with `File.Exists`

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution that did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of moving file by file, you can use `Directory.Move(string, string)` method.

Syntax

```
   Directory.Move(sourceDirPath, DestinationDirPath)
```

For more information: [Directory.Move Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does not work if the File does not exist, though.

Comment: @PaulKertscher, you can add extra check before you move dictionary to check file exists or not. Question talk about moving all files from one folder to another. I believe OP is not expecting any single file to move from one place to another

Comment: Yeah, of course. Anyway, after rereading my comment I don't think that I wrote what I wanted to to express. I meant: It does not work to copy files into a non-empty directory, which is a common use case (and OP did not express that they wanted to move the files to a new dir, but to the desktop, which most likely already contains files)